# What does 'bundle exec rake' versus rake do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What is the difference between doing:

```
bundle exec rake
```

and

```
rake
```

I see people doing both, I never do `bundle` before my commands, curious what the reason for it is?

Comment: I think this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588674/what-does-bundle-exec-rake-dbmigrate-mean could have the answer

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588674/what-does-bundle-exec-rake-mean

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`bundle exec` executes a command in the context of the bundle.
 This command executes the command, making all gems specified in the `Gemfile` available to require in Ruby programs.
 Very useful when you have many applications with different versions of gems used 
 in them.

Please see docs for more information: http://gembundler.com/man/bundle-exec.1.html

Answer (score 15):

`bundle exec` runs the command after it in the environment of Bundler. So say you had rake 0.9 in you Gemfile, but rake 10 installed in RubyGems.`bundle exec rake` will run rake 0.9 instead of rake 10.