# Gem is not available after bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundle, ruby-on-rails-4, gemfile

I have a Gemfile where I add a new gem

```
gem 'activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter', git: "https://github.com/rsim/oracle-enhanced.git", branch: "rails4"
```

When I run `bundle install` I get

```
> bundle install
Updating https://github.com/rsim/oracle-enhanced.git
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
...
Using activerecord (4.0.0)
Using activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter (1.4.2) from https://github.com/rsim/oracle-enhanced.git (at rails4) 
Using bundler (1.3.5)
...
```

But when I call `gem list`, the gem is missing. If I try to load this gem in the irb, I get

```
irb
require 'rubygems'
=> false
gem 'activerecord'
=> true
gem 'activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter'
Gem::LoadError: Could not find 'activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter' (>= 0) among 49 total gem(s)
```

I do not understand this behavior. I have several gems added to my Gemfile this way and all of them are working.

My system for the test:

- RVM
- ruby 2.0.0p195
- new gemset
- new rails 4 project without any modification except this gem in the Gemfile
- I tried it with two different users
- Ubuntu 12.04

If I call `gem install activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter`, this gem is installed, but not from the 'rails4' branch and I would like to use the Gemfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling `bundle exec irb` so you will load irb in specific Gemset scope instead of system one.

Comment: Thank you. I still do not know, why this gem is not listed (all others are) using `gem list`, but `bundle exec gem list` shows the gem. `bundle exec irb` works as well.

Comment: Maybe that link will help you, generally speaking, `bundle exec` runs command in current Gemset scope: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588674/what-does-bundle-exec-rake-mean