# Rails gives error when using PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku, sqlite

I am trying to use PostgreSQL instead of SQLite3 for my Rails app because PostgreSQL is required by Heroku, where I want to deploy the app. Starting my app with the Postgres flag (i.e., `--databse=postgresql`) works fine. However, after adding `gem twitter-boostrap-rails` to my `Gemfile` and running `bundle install` I get this error about SQLite3:

> ```
> active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:190:in
> ```
>
> `rescue in spec': Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter, but the
>   gem is not loaded. Add`gem 'sqlite3'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its
>   version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord)

Here is my `Gemfile`:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem "therubyracer"
gem "less-rails"
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.4'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster.              
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background.   
gem 'spring',        group: :development

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production>
```

And here is my `database.yml`:

```
----------


# PostgreSQL. Versions 8.2 and up are supported.
#
# Install the pg driver:
#   gem install pg
# On OS X with Homebrew:
#   gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/local/bin/pg_config
# On OS X with MacPorts:
#   gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/opt/local/lib/postgresql84/bin/pg_config
# On Windows:
#   gem install pg
#       Choose the win32 build.
#       Install PostgreSQL and put its /bin directory on your path.
#
# Configure Using Gemfile
# gem 'pg'
#
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see rails configuration guide
  # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *default
```

Why am I getting this error, and how do I fix the problem?

Comment: can you please clear me one thing which adapter you want to use? in gem file I see that it is `pg` but you told you got error of sqlite 3

Comment: I want to use postgresql, as that is required for hosting on Heroku

Comment: check your `Gemfile.lock` probably its a dependency to one of the gems you installed

Comment: No sqlite3 is not listed in my Gemfile.lock

Answer (score 2):

try running `bundle update` and then `bundle exec rails s` - also you are gonna need to specify more parameters in your database.yml like your host, etc. should look something like this:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: some_database_name
  pool: 5
  host: localhost
  username: your_username (or root) if just dev
  password: your_password
```

keep in mind since this is all dev, the security of the username/pw doesn't really matter as its not housing any important data/not accessible outside your machine

Comment: Every thing works until I do: "rails g bootstrap:install", I get the sqlite3 error again

Comment: try `bundle exec rails g bootstrap:install`

Comment: Ok that works, but why?? now Im getting "user does not exist" when I do rake db:create db:migrate

Comment: read this answer for why it works :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588674/what-does-bundle-exec-rake-mean as to your other error, its possibly because you have your database username/password combination wrong. Check how you installed postgresql and make a user for it

Comment: @user1020372 are you still having issues with this? Can we close this question? :)

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the database config for development **explicitly**. Looks like the database.yml is not aligned correctly.

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: your_db
  host: 127.0.0.1
  pool: 5
  username: your_db_username
  password: your_db_password
```