# Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - java

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When executing $ bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start then it starts successfully

```
$ bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start
[deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
Removing stale PID file at /home/user/practice/site_ad/solr/pids/development/sunspot-solr-development.pid
Successfully started Solr ...
```

But while executing rake sunspot:solr:run getting this error

```
rake aborted!
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - java
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/sunspot_solr-2.1.1/lib/sunspot   /solr/server.rb:105:in `exec'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/sunspot_solr-2.1.1/lib/sunspot/solr/server.rb:105:in `block in run'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/sunspot_solr-2.1.1/lib/sunspot/solr/server.rb:104:in `run'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/sunspot_solr-2.1.1/lib/sunspot/solr/tasks.rb:11:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => sunspot:solr:run
```

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6588708/326543) out.

Comment: Why is "java" included in the question title if this question is about Ruby on Rails? Are you using JRuby?