# I need to put 'bundle exec' before all my commands

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, bundler

Recently (few minutes ago) I deleted all my gems using:

```
rvm gemset empty mygems
rvm gemset delete global
```

I created my own gemset name.

```
rvm gemset create myname
```

I created a .ruby-gemset file in my project with myname

I did a: bundle install on my app so I have a fresh install.

Now I need to run the command like this to run my server:

```
 bundle exec rails s
```

Before I was able to simply run: rails s.
Now it gives me this stack:

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Name-2:rails-app namename$ rails s
    /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/ext/parser.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault
    ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [universal.x86_64-darwin14]

    -- Crash Report log information --------------------------------------------
       See Crash Report log file under the one of following:
         * ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter
         * /Library/Logs/CrashReporter
         * ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
         * /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
       the more detail of.

    -- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
    c:0033 p:-17565584435966 s:0098 e:000097 TOP    [FINISH]
    c:0032 p:---- s:0096 e:000095 CFUNC  :require
    c:0031 p:0009 s:0092 e:000091 CLASS  /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/ext.rb:13
    c:0030 p:0011 s:0090 e:000089 CLASS  /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/ext.rb:12
    c:0029 p:0057 s:0088 e:000087 TOP    /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/ext.rb:9 [FINISH]
    c:0028 p:---- s:0086 e:000085 CFUNC  :require
    c:0027 p:0019 s:0082 e:000081 CLASS  /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json.rb:58
    c:0026 p:0017 s:0080 e:000079 TOP    /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json.rb:54 [FINISH]
    c:0025 p:---- s:0078 e:000077 CFUNC  :require
    c:0024 p:0009 s:0074 e:000073 TOP    /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/activesupport-4.0.12/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/to_json.r [FINISH]
    c:0023 p:---- s:0072 e:000071 CFUNC  :require
    c:0022 p:0071 s:0068 e:000067 TOP    /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/activesupport-4.0.12/lib/active_support/core_ext/object.rb:11 [FINISH]
    c:0021 p:---- s:0066 e:000065 CFUNC  :require
    c:0020 p:0023 s:0062 e:000061 TOP    /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/railties-4.0.12/lib/rails/configuration.rb:3 [FINISH]
    c:0019 p:---- s:0060 e:000059 CFUNC  :require
    c:0018 p:0015 s:0056 e:000055 TOP    /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/railties-4.0.12/lib/rails/railtie.rb:2 [FINISH]
    c:0017 p:---- s:0054 e:000053 CFUNC  :require
    c:0016 p:0007 s:0050 e:000049 TOP    /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/railties-4.0.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:1 [FINISH]
    c:0015 p:---- s:0048 e:000047 CFUNC  :require
    c:0014 p:0031 s:0044 e:000043 TOP    /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/railties-4.0.12/lib/rails/application.rb:4 [FINISH]
    c:0013 p:---- s:0042 e:000041 CFUNC  :require
    c:0012 p:0047 s:0038 e:000037 TOP    /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/railties-4.0.12/lib/rails.rb:9 [FINISH]
    c:0011 p:---- s:0036 e:000035 CFUNC  :require
    c:0010 p:0007 s:0032 e:000031 TOP    /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/railties-4.0.12/lib/rails/all.rb:1 [FINISH]
    c:0009 p:---- s:0030 e:000029 CFUNC  :require
    c:0008 p:0026 s:0026 e:000025 TOP    /Users/namename/Documents/workspaces/rails-app/config/application.rb:3 [FINISH]
    c:0007 p:---- s:0024 e:000023 CFUNC  :require
    c:0006 p:0014 s:0020 e:000019 BLOCK  /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/railties-4.0.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:74 [FINISH]
    c:0005 p:---- s:0017 e:000016 CFUNC  :tap
    c:0004 p:0562 s:0014 e:000013 TOP    /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/railties-4.0.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:71 [FINISH]
    c:0003 p:---- s:0008 e:000007 CFUNC  :require
    c:0002 p:0045 s:0004 E:001268 EVAL   script/rails:6 [FINISH]
    c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 E:0023d8 TOP    [FINISH]

    script/rails:6:in `<main>'
    script/rails:6:in `require'
    /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/railties-4.0.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
    /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/railties-4.0.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
    /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/railties-4.0.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:74:in `block in <top (required)>'
    /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/railties-4.0.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:74:in `require'
    /Users/namename/Documents/workspaces/rails-app/config/application.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    /Users/namename/Documents/workspaces/rails-app/config/application.rb:3:in `require'
    /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/railties-4.0.12/lib/rails/all.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/railties-4.0.12/lib/rails/all.rb:1:in `require'
    /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/railties-4.0.12/lib/rails.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/railties-4.0.12/lib/rails.rb:9:in `require'
    /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/railties-4.0.12/lib/rails/application.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/railties-4.0.12/lib/rails/application.rb:4:in `require'
    /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/railties-4.0.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/railties-4.0.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:1:in `require'
    /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/railties-4.0.12/lib/rails/railtie.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/railties-4.0.12/lib/rails/railtie.rb:2:in `require'
    /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/railties-4.0.12/lib/rails/configuration.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/railties-4.0.12/lib/rails/configuration.rb:3:in `require'
    /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/activesupport-4.0.12/lib/active_support/core_ext/object.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/activesupport-4.0.12/lib/active_support/core_ext/object.rb:11:in `require'
    /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/activesupport-4.0.12/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/to_json.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/activesupport-4.0.12/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/to_json.rb:3:in `require'
    /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json.rb:54:in `<top (required)>'
    /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json.rb:58:in `<module:JSON>'
    /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json.rb:58:in `require'
    /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/ext.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/ext.rb:12:in `<module:JSON>'
    /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/ext.rb:13:in `<module:Ext>'
    /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/ext.rb:13:in `require'

    -- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------

    -- Other runtime information -----------------------------------------------

    * Loaded script: script/rails

    * Loaded features:

        0 enumerator.so
        1 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin14/enc/encdb.bundle
        2 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin14/enc/trans/transdb.bundle
        3 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin14/rbconfig.rb
        4 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/compatibility.rb
        5 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/defaults.rb
        6 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/deprecate.rb
        7 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/errors.rb
        8 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/version.rb
        9 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/requirement.rb
       10 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/platform.rb
       11 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb
       12 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/exceptions.rb
       13 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb
       14 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/thread.rb
       15 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb
       16 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb
       17 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems.rb
       18 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/path_support.rb
       19 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb
       20 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin14/pathname.bundle
       21 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/pathname.rb
       22 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/constants.rb
       23 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/user_interaction.rb
       24 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin14/etc.bundle
       25 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/config_file.rb
       26 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb
       27 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/current_ruby.rb
       28 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb
       29 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb
       30 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/gem_path_manipulation.rb
       31 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/gem_helpers.rb
       32 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/match_platform.rb
       33 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/rubygems_ext.rb
       34 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/version.rb
       35 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler.rb
       36 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/settings.rb
       37 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin14/digest.bundle
       38 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/digest.rb
       39 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin14/digest/sha1.bundle
       40 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/set.rb
       41 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/definition.rb
       42 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/dependency.rb
       43 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/ruby_dsl.rb
       44 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/dsl.rb
       45 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/source_list.rb
       46 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/source.rb
       47 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/common.rb
       48 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/generic.rb
       49 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/ftp.rb
       50 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/http.rb
       51 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/https.rb
       52 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/ldap.rb
       53 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/ldaps.rb
       54 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/mailto.rb
       55 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri.rb
       56 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/cgi/core.rb
       57 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/cgi/util.rb
       58 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/cgi/cookie.rb
       59 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/cgi.rb
       60 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin14/socket.bundle
       61 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/socket.rb
       62 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin14/fcntl.bundle
       63 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/timeout.rb
       64 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin14/openssl.bundle
       65 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl/bn.rb
       66 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl/cipher.rb
       67 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin14/stringio.bundle
       68 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl/config.rb
       69 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl/digest.rb
       70 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl/x509.rb
       71 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl/buffering.rb
       72 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl/ssl.rb
       73 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl.rb
       74 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/securerandom.rb
       75 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/resolv.rb
       76 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb
       77 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/text.rb
       78 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/name_tuple.rb
       79 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb
       80 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb
       81 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/ruby_version.rb
       82 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin14/strscan.bundle
       83 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/source/path.rb
       84 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/source/git.rb
       85 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/lockfile_parser.rb
       86 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/lazy_specification.rb
       87 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb
       88 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/forwardable.rb
       89 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb
       90 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/environment.rb
       91 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb
       92 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/index.rb
       93 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/remote_specification.rb
       94 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/endpoint_specification.rb
       95 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/dep_proxy.rb
       96 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/setup.rb
       97 /Users/namename/Documents/workspaces/rails-app/config/boot.rb
       98 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/optparse.rb
       99 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/thread_safe-0.3.4/lib/thread_safe/version.rb
      100 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/delegate.rb
      101 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/thread_safe-0.3.4/lib/thread_safe/synchronized_delegator.rb
      102 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/thread_safe-0.3.4/lib/thread_safe.rb
      103 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/activesupport-4.0.12/lib/active_support/core_ext/array/prepend_and_append.rb
      104 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/activesupport-4.0.12/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/deep_merge.rb
      105 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/activesupport-4.0.12/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/except.rb
      106 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/activesupport-4.0.12/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/slice.rb
      107 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n/version.rb
      108 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n/exceptions.rb
      109 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n/interpolate/ruby.rb
      110 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n.rb
      111 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/activesupport-4.0.12/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb
      112 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n/config.rb
      113 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/activesupport-4.0.12/lib/active_support/i18n.rb
      114 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/thread_safe-0.3.4/lib/thread_safe/non_concurrent_cache_backend.rb
      115 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/thread_safe-0.3.4/lib/thread_safe/mri_cache_backend.rb
      116 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/thread_safe-0.3.4/lib/thread_safe/cache.rb
      117 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/activesupport-4.0.12/lib/active_support/inflector/inflections.rb
      118 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/activesupport-4.0.12/lib/active_support/inflections.rb
      119 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/activesupport-4.0.12/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb
      120 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/activesupport-4.0.12/lib/active_support/dependencies/autoload.rb
      121 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/activesupport-4.0.12/lib/active_support/version.rb
      122 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/activesupport-4.0.12/lib/active_support/core_ext/array/extract_options.rb
      123 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/activesupport-4.0.12/lib/active_support/core_ext/class/attribute_accessors.rb
      124 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/activesupport-4.0.12/lib/active_support/concern.rb
      125 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/activesupport-4.0.12/lib/active_support/logger_silence.rb
      126 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/logger.rb
      127 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/activesupport-4.0.12/lib/active_support/logger.rb
      128 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/activesupport-4.0.12/lib/active_support.rb
      129 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/activesupport-4.0.12/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb
      130 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/activesupport-4.0.12/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/singleton_class.rb
      131 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/activesupport-4.0.12/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/remove_method.rb
      132 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/activesupport-4.0.12/lib/active_support/core_ext/class/attribute.rb
      133 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/activesupport-4.0.12/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/delegation.rb
      134 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/singleton.rb
      135 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/activesupport-4.0.12/lib/active_support/deprecation/instance_delegator.rb
      136 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/activesupport-4.0.12/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb
      137 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mutex_m.rb
      ...
      ...
      209 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/activesupport-4.0.12/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/conversions.rb
      210 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/activesupport-4.0.12/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/zones.rb
      211 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/activesupport-4.0.12/lib/active_support/time.rb
      212 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/activesupport-4.0.12/lib/active_support/core_ext/array/wrap.rb
      213 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/activesupport-4.0.12/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/reverse_merge.rb
      214 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/activesupport-4.0.12/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/conversions.rb
      215 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/activesupport-4.0.12/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/conversions.rb
      216 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/activesupport-4.0.12/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/instance_variables.rb
      217 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/version.rb
      218 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/ostruct.rb
      219 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/generic_object.rb
      220 /Users/namename/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@myname/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/common.rb

    [NOTE]
    You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
    Bug reports are welcome.
    For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html
```

Comment: `bundle exec` runs a script in the context of the current bundle. You should always use `bundle exec`, even though it may sometimes work without it. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/6588708/847857

Comment: ok good to know. I was a bit worry because I do not know if my passenger server is running 'bundle exec rails' or just 'rails' so I wanted to be sure I do not break anything in production if I repeat the same configuration I did locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your stack trace mixes parts from your RVM ruby and your system ruby. These are not compatible. It seems your RVM setup is incomplete/broken. If you don't want to dig in there and find the actual cause, you might want to complete remove and reinstall RVM:

```
# completely remove rvm, including all rvm-installed rubies and gems
rvm implode
# re-install RVM
\curl -sSL "https://get.rvm.io" | bash -s stable
```