# rails sudo + <any command> will throw an error of different ruby versions (installed vs. Gemfile)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

Every time a command is executes with `sudo` (for instance: `sudo rake db:seed` or `sudo bundle`) an error is thrown: `Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.1`.
When I hit `ruby -v` it's `ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-linux]` so I guess it's not the problem.
In addition I use rvm to manage the versions and when I list them with `rvm list` the output is:

```
rvm rubies

=* ruby-2.2.1 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

So what causes this error to be thrown? It has something to do with the root user configuration?

Answer (score 1):

You can try command `rvmsudo` (more information [here](https://rvm.io/integration/sudo)).

Comment: Seems like this is the real answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sudo bundle exec rake db:seed`, `sudo bundle exec bundle`.

Using bundle exec makes everything standardized according to your current Gemfile. See: [What does bundle exec rake mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588674/what-does-bundle-exec-rake-mean)

Comment: Ok, try `sudo bundle exec bundle` first, then back to that command. This first command should set up your gems to match your gemfile, than you can do the other once you have the correct gem configurations.

Comment: got the same error for the `sudo bundle exec bundle` command.

Comment: In my opinion, rvm is troublesome and not easy to debug. You can follow this gist to switch to rbenv: https://gist.github.com/brentertz/1384279 once you're using rbenv things should be easier with ruby versions. Otherwise, not sure what the issue is as `bundle` or `sudo bundle` should be installing your correct ruby version.