# error setting up MySQL database for RoR

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and am having trouble setting up my first MySQL database.

I followed the instructions on here: https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.12-sierra

And I reached the very end where it asks you to run "rake db:create".  When I execute this in the terminal, I get the following error:

```
MacBook-Air-de-myusername% rake db:create
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- bundler/setup
/Users/myusername/splash/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/myusername/splash/config/application.rb:1:in `require_relative'
/Users/myusername/splash/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/myusername/splash/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
/Users/myusername/splash/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Can anyone advise on what is happening?  I know that I have "cd"-ed into the correct directory, so that can't be it.

Comment: Do you have bundler gem installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install **bundler gem** and run `bundle install`:

```
$ gem install bundler
$ bundle install
```

Now run `rake` again:

```
$ rake db:create
```

If that doesn't work, then run the complete command:

```
$ bundle exec rake db:create
```

To understand more about `bundle` command, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588674/what-does-bundle-exec-rake-mean).

Comment: I ran into an error on "bundle install" because it says it doesn't work with Ruby 2.0.0.  The thing is, I've already installed 2.4.0.  However: when I run "ruby -v" it says it's 2.0.0, but when I try to (re)install 2.4.0 it says:

`rbenv: /Users/myusername/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0 already exists`

Comment: Rbenv.  I tried to do RVM but ran into some errors that a noob like myself couldn't figure out.

Comment: @7QVM OK, try running `rbenv global 2.4.0` to change your ruby version. Then run `bundle install` again (check first with `ruby -v` that your version changed successfully).

Comment: It doesn't seem to have had any effect: 
`MacBook-Air-de-myusername% rbenv global 2.4.0
MacBook-Air-de-myusername% ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [universal.x86_64-darwin16]`

Comment: @7QVM Did you specified a `RBENV_VERSION` variable? If so, run `echo $RBENV_VERSION` to see which version it specifies; if it is `2.0.0` change it to `2.4.0`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144145/discussion-between-gerry-and-7qvm).

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
gem install bundler
bundle install
bundle exec rake db:create
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are in incorrect folder.

try `cd splash`

then run following command:

```
bundle install
bundle exec rake db:create
```