# Bundle exec rake versus rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

What is the difference between for example using

```
rails db:migrate
```

and

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

when using the rails framework? It seems to do the same for me...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588674/what-does-bundle-exec-rake-mean gives a pretty good answer of what adding `bundle exec` does. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does bundle exec rake mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588674/what-does-bundle-exec-rake-mean)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two fold. As of rails 5 you can substitute rails and rake for db:migrate. What you are really changing is adding `bundle exec` which is telling it to execute the rake from the application's bundler instead of your platform bundler.

For instance, you have `bundler v15` on your mac, and `bundler v12` on the application. bundle exec rake will use `bundler v12`, but rake will use `bundler v15`.

Answer (score 1):

```
rails db:migrate vs bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Internally rails is proxying commands to rake.

[See this link](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/908c011395cc9e3ea1bb195f9d1bd30a9d9df98f/railties/lib/rails/commands/rake_proxy.rb)