# Bundler 2, Gemfile not found error when running any rails or rake command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I am setting a new app, stack is:

```
ruby: 2.6.1 (using rvm)
rails: 5.2.2
bundler: 2.0.1
```

Now thing is, bundler 2 doesn't use `Gemfile` at all, i have proper `gems.rb` and `gems.locked` and everything was working properly until i pulled some code from a co-worker which got merged.

Issue is whenever i run any `rake` or `rails` command i get this error:

```
/path/to/proj/Gemfile not found
```

I then even tried going back to old master when that code was not merged and issue is still there. So it is probably not something in the code i pulled.
And issue seems persistent in different machines.

I know there are other issues which have similar errors of `Gemfile not found` but those are mostly those which had wrong directory opened or some gem issued fixed by `bundle update` or `gem update` type commands, this is not that issue because. This is something else, because bundler 2 doesn't even need `Gemfile`.

Comment: Are you sure that you actually use the `2.0.1` version of bundler and not another version? How did you verify that?

Comment: Well, i run bundle -v and i get 2.0.1, also bundler 1 doesn't pick gems.rb, it needs Gemfile, so i am sure, yeah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like rails doesn't support using `gems.rb` and `gems.locked`. https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/31295

You could try what that guy did and edit some files, or you could rename your `gems.rb` back to `Gemfile` and `gems.locked` back to `Gemfile.lock`

Comment: Thanks for the link, don't know why i missed this one in my google search. It fixed the issue, thanks

Comment: BTW, i don't know why, but appending rails with bundle exec was also making it work somehow.

Comment: hmm, if running it with bundle exec makes it work, then it seems like its just defaulting to the wrong bundler version or something. `bundle exec` ensures that it runs the command in the right bundler context, you can see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588674/what-does-bundle-exec-rake-mean for some more details if you want